# STRAPi Error connecting to the Mongo database. Incomplete key value pair for option

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb atlas cluster while following the [documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/databases.html#mongodb-installation) but it gave me an `Error connecting to the Mongo database. Incomplete key value pair for option`.

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "uri": "mongodb://vafflehauz:Vafflehauz312**?@company-shard-00-00-qreis.mongodb.net:27017,company-shard-00-01-qreis.mongodb.net:27017,company-shard-00-02-qreis.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=company-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
      },
      "options": {
        "ssl": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here`s my [config/development/database.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f56Hz.png).

I'm using strapi 3.0.0-beta version

Comment: The question mark in your password is being interpreted as an option in the URI. try using %3F in its place.

Comment: I tried changing it to Vafflehauz312**%3F and it works! Ty very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joe Drumgoole for pointing out my password was the issue and now it works.

> The question mark in your password is being interpreted as an option in the URI. try using %3F in its place. – Joe Drumgoole

```js
"uri": "mongodb://vafflehauz:Vafflehauz312**%3F@company-shard-00-00-qreis.mongodb.net:27017,company-shard-00-01-qreis.mongodb.net:27017,company-shard-00-02-qreis.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=company-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```