# unable to connect to aws documentdb using pymongo

Tags: pymongo, aws-documentdb

from xml.dom.minidom import Document

Here i am using Documentdb with python.

```
    def get_data(col, filters):
        myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@prod-docdb-2022-09-02-06-10-32.cluster-cqjdkdkioshsjsaafcooj9.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/school?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false&&tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
        mydb = myclient["school"]
        mycol = mydb[col]
        res = mycol.find(filters)
        return loads(dumps(res))
```

When i am connecting to db it is showing below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/automations/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 330, in split_options
    options = _parse_options(opts, "&")
File "/home/ubuntu/automations/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 161, in _parse_options
    key, value = uriopt.split("=")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "german.py", line 172, in <module>
    create_data_arabic("Egyptian (Arabic)")
File "german.py", line 107, in create_data_arabic
    curriculums = get_data("curriculums", {})
File "german.py", line 15, in get_data
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@prod-docdb-2022-09-02-06-10-32.cluster-cqioaafcooj9.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/school?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false&&tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
File "/home/ubuntu/automations/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 726, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
File "/home/ubuntu/automations/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 511, in parse_uri
    options.update(split_options(opts, validate, warn, normalize))
File "/home/ubuntu/automations/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 338, in split_options
    raise InvalidURI("MongoDB URI options are key=value pairs.")
pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: MongoDB URI options are key=value pairs.
```

Please take  a look what can be the issue. I have the ssl key also available inside that folder.

Comment: Looks like it's duplicative of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883746/strapi-error-connecting-to-the-mongo-database-incomplete-key-value-pair-for-opt.

Replace the question mark with %3F.

Answer (score 0):

The error logs point to a ValueError in the URI string when defining the MongoClient. String 'school' after the host port is not a valid key for [split_option](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/uri_parser.html#pymongo.uri_parser.split_options) method.

Comment: The issue with the URI is actually here: `retryWrites=false&&tls=true` , there are two ampersand signs and pymongo can't parse it correctly.